# How can I check the length of an argument in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, arguments, string-length

Let's say I want to check if the first argument is 2 characters long. I tried

```
if [ ${#$1} -e 2]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Don't use $ in the parameter expansion
- Use `-eq` for numerical comparison
- Add a space before the `]`:

All in all:

```
if [ ${#1} -eq 2 ]
then
  echo "It's two characters long"
fi
```